# How to get a list of variable name in global scope in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I believe I might have a memory leak in my code(back-end , server-side. express). My assumption is that the cause of the problem could be due to forgotten global variables declared in some files, which I haven't cleared after use. Are there any solutions available to retrieve a list of all global variable names? My plan is to review each one to identify and fix the issue. Thank you.

Comment: You could print a list of the properties of the `global` object but I doubt that a leak could be from there. Maybe look also around async callbak closures capturing references with shorter lifetime or this kind of things...